# How to get value of DataTable Row in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i am learning `asp.net` with `c#` by myself, and i have a problem with DataRows, 
in db i have `users` table and there is `isadmin` column which value is `int`,
i want to redirect users to different page and admins to admin page, but the problem is all users redirects to admin page.

Here is my code;

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
        conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username, pass FROM users 
                                where username = '"+txtUser.Text+"'
                                and pass='"+txtPass.Text+"'"
                                , conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select username, isadmin From users", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        da1.Fill(dt1);

        conn.Close();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["id"] = txtUser.Text;
            if (dt1.Rows[0]["isadmin"].ToString() == "1")
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/admin.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
            }


            //Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");

            Session.RemoveAll();
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            //lblMsg.Text= msg ;

                /*Response.Write("<script>
                alert('Please enter valid Username and Password')
                </script>"); */
        }
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: why do you have 2 different query that queries to same table?

Comment: seems like all users which you are fetching have `isadmin` column value 1.

Comment: hi have you tried have you looked into data of the database . Also can you print the value of dt1.Rows[0]["Isadmin"] to see what is output ?

Comment: sees like value of dt1.Rows[0]["Isadmin"] is 1

Comment: Always use parametrized queries not string concatenation to build your sql qeueries. Otherwise you are open for sql injection(among other issues).

Comment: dt is filled via "SELECT username, pass" and with this does NOT contain IsAdmin. The query for dt has to be extended by the IsAdmin column.

Comment: @Badiparmagi i was trying many things this was my last try, that is why i have 2 query for same table.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad you are right, event isadmin has different value for users, it returns always 1.

Comment: @YashveerSingh i tried to print the value, event values are different for users the output is always 1.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you for your warning, as i mentioned im learning it, i will try to parametrize the query.

Comment: so that means you found your issue I think answer as well : Happy coding :)

Comment: In your second query first row always has isadmin 1 that is why you are getting worng results.

Comment: Thanks for everyone for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the first query with `dt` as it's based on a single user. The problem is `dt1` gets all users and the first record in that datatable is an admin

`if (dt.Rows[0]["isadmin"].ToString() == "1") {`

Remove the second query with `dt1` and make sure you add **isadmin** to the first SQL query.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username, pass, isadmin FROM users where username = @UserName and pass= @Pass", conn);
```

See how I use parameterized username and password, that is to protect against SQL injection, definitely read up on that!!!

Comment: how can i try to get isadmin value from `dt`?

Comment: Add the IsAdmin field to the first SQL query, I gave you all the reasons this doesn't work to try and teach you so you can learn to work this out yourself in future, Zohar gave you a copy/paste code answer that gives it to you without any effort. Give a man a fish, feed him for a day, teach a man how to fish and feed him for life. When debugging you have to go after the bug like a dog fetching a bone, good luck mate

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code:

1. All users are redirected to the admin page since you are checking the `isAdmin` in the wrong query. 
   Your second query has no where clause which means it will return all the users in the table. The first user it returns has the `isAdmin` value of `1`.
   You don't actually need two queries, just one.
2. You must use parameterized queries, otherwise you are leaving an open door to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
3. wrap all `IDisposable` instances in a [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

Your code should look more like this:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username, pass, isadmin FROM users where username = @UserName and pass=@Pass", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUser.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPass.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }   

    }
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Session["id"] = txtUser.Text;
        if (dt1.Rows[0]["isadmin"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/admin.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
        }


        //Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");

        Session.RemoveAll();
    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        //lblMsg.Text= msg ;

        //Response.Write("<script>alert('Please enter valid Username and Password')</script>");
    }

}
```

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer

Comment: You are right value is always 1, i was trying many things to solve the problem, this is my last try, i will try to parametrize the query to avoid sql injection.

Comment: your coding is complicated for me, no doubt you are professional, can you give me a link which explains "wrap all IDisposable instances in a using statement.". thank you for your help

Comment: The `using` in my answer is also a link to the relevant page in MSDN...

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd =
        new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT username, pass, isadmin FROM users where username = '" + txtUser.Text + "' and pass='" + txtPass.Text +
            "'", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    conn.Close();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Session["id"] = txtUser.Text;
        if (dt.Rows[0]["isadmin"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/admin.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
        }


        //Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");

        Session.RemoveAll();
    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        //lblMsg.Text= msg ;

        //Response.Write("<script>alert('Please enter valid Username and Password')</script>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first query you need to get `isadmin` also and on the base of that result you can check either it is 1 or not and can redirect to what ever page you like. So it will be as follow:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username, pass, isadmin FROM users where username = '"+txtUser.Text+"' and pass='"+txtPass.Text+"'", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Session["id"] = txtUser.Text;
        if (dt.Rows[0]["isadmin"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/admin.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
        }
        //Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
        Session.RemoveAll();
    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        //lblMsg.Text= msg ;
        //Response.Write("<script>alert('Please enter valid Username and Password')</script>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your second query lacks the filter on a user name:

```
Select username, isadmin From users
```

So whatever it fetches - if the first row contains 1 as IsAdmin, all users will be redirected to the admin page.

Comment: dt does not contain the column IsAdmin

Comment: i have tried like this; `Select isadmin From users` but no hope!

Comment: You should try SELECT username, pass, isadmin FROM users in the first cmd